# Laravel validation array, access to element on validation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have an array of elements that i want to validate, this array have this form

```
{
    "slugs" : {
        1 : "prueba",
        2 : "test"
}
```

Slugs is the input `<input name="slugs[{{ $lang->id }}]">` and the numbers are the id of the language `1 = spanish / 2 = english`.

What i want is to validate these field uniqueness, in a form request like this

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        //
        'slugs.*' => Rule::unique('translation_entries')->where(function($query) {
            //here i want to access the * that represent the lang id
            //like this $query->where('lang_id','=',$query->*);
        })
    ];
}
```

can i access the index `*` inside the unique Rule class?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using Laravel >=5.5 you can use a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures)

```
'slugs.*' => [
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        $id = str_after($attribute, '.');

        if (\DB::table('translation_entries')->where('lang_id', $id)->where('slug', $value)->exists()) {
            $fail('The slug has already been taken.');
        }
    },
],
```

Change `'slug'` to be the name of the column on the `translation_entries` table (if different).